# How to find all empty subtrees in XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath

The overall goal is to remove all empty nodes--including nodes which would be made empty if the child empty nodes were removed. The following:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>
```

will remove empty nodes, but will leave empty nodes that had only empty nodes in them previously. I think I need an xpath that will match all nodes that all descendants of which have no attributes and no text nodes (ignoring whitespace).

Comment: (+1). See my answer for a correct solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(.//@*) and not(descendent::text())]"/>
```

**Notice** the `and` operator. Using `or` does not solve the problem.

Comment: In logic this would be equivalent `*[not(.//@* or descendent::text())]`, but I do not know if it is difficult to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer...

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(.//text() | .//@*)]"/>
```

Just find all nodes that have no descendant text or attributes, right? Is there something I'm missing such that this won't do what I think it will in some cases? In my simple test, this seemed to work.

Comment: This *is* correct, but may cause some XSLT processors that don't have good optimizers to perform the union before concluding this is a match. See my solution, which might have a better chance of being optimized, as it uses explicit `and`.